# What should I be aware of when not inheriting the membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

At this point in the development of our web application we are slowly finding the needs of the application to differ from what the membership provider offers by default. As we implement new features we are overloading the default methods and changing a lot of things to the point that it's getting confusing and the point of inheriting the MembershipProvider does not seem necessarry any longer.

My question is: besides the use of the custom controls like Login, CreateUserWizard (which we are already not using), RecoverPassword, etc. what is the benefit of using the MembershipProvider? I have already looked into such things as encrypting password and I feel that the Crypto helper class will provide that to us. What other things should I be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot enumerate a list of things to be aware of off the top of my head, but I would encourage you to get rid of the `MembershipProvider` as soon as possible anyway. Don't invest any more time in bending it to suit your needs.

The `MembershipProvider`'s architecture doesn't scale to the complexity of real-world applications and it is only really suited for 30 minute on-stage demonstrations.

Comment: I hear this often but I also hear arguments from the other side stating I should use the MembershipProvider despite these short comings. I'm not sure which side to go for but I'd rather have the application code be more readable by not having a lot of useless or overloaded methods!